# How to understand "likes to" in this sentence?

Tags: word-meaning

What does "likes to" mean in this sentence?

> Copenhagen ***likes to*** be known as the city that never sleeps.

What is the equivalent word or expression to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's exactly the same *like* as in *I like to swim* or *I like to drink whiskey* or *I like to be dropped out of airplanes with a parachute*.

The writer is *personifying* the city of Copenhagen—treating the city as a person, when what is actually meant is that the inhabitants of the city (or the administration, or the Tourism Office, or the owners of hotels and restaurants and nightclubs) would **like** you to think of Copenhagen as the city that never sleeps, where hot entertainment is available around the clock.